# Optimal way to create and use ODP.NET connection

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I am trying to understand what the most efficient yet maintainable way to create and use connections with ODP.NET.

My standard approach to writing functions in VB.NET that use ODP.NET is something like this:

```
Function GetDataTable() As DataTable

    Using Connection = New OracleConnection(connectionStringNHH)
        Using Command As OracleCommand = Connection.CreateCommand()
            Using DataAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter()

                'Do stuff, fill dt

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return dt

End Function
```

However, as per the Oracle documentation:

> logging in and out of the database is an extremely resource-intensive operation [[1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/connection_strategies.html#GUID-841C6E1B-00A3-41AA-A5A8-9740E4EBA929)]

Does creating and disposing of the connection object log in and out of the database every time this function is called, or does the session persist application-wide somehow?

If not, should I use a public connection object through my application? That seems bad practice to me for a number of reasons.

Comment: This is the right thing to do. Unless you change your setting, connection pooling will take care of the problem mention.

Comment: ADO.NET generally works such that the actual database connection exists at a lower level and it will remain open for some time after you close the high-level connection.

Comment: Thanks both. That was my feeling but couldn't find any documentation explicitly stating it (perhaps some shoddy google-fu).

Comment: don't make any of your oracle objects public...once you expose they, they will cross assembly boundaries and then changing your database reference down the line becomes a headache...if you need to expose objects...expose their underlying interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you get a connection pool inside of OracleConnection. Connection lifetime and corresponding sessions open with the database will be controlled by the pool. See the ODP.NET doc for all the details.

The best practice is to make sure these connections and other oracle objects get closed and disposed.

Here's a best practice slide deck that should help:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/oow18dotnetperfbp-5212811.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this, helpful link.